# Short film(?) featuring a vampire and an elderly Van Helsing

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I have a vague memory of this scene that is possibly from a short film.  It's possible it was done as a flashback of some kind, or that it was part of some horror anthology.

I saw it at some point in the last ten years, and if memory serves the production values seemed sufficient that it must have been made at least after the year 2000.  It could well be much newer than that.  I *might* have seen it on YouTube.  I am unsure if the audio language was English or not.

It's a confrontation between an elderly man in his house and a vampire.  I believe the vampire kills his housekeeper.  The elderly man conceals a crossbow, while the vampire monologues for a bit (I think), which he then uses to kill the vampire.

The camera then shows outside the house, and there's a sign which says 'Helsing', which at that point reveals to the viewer that this elderly man is the legendary vampire hunter.

The bits that I am most certain on are the concealed crossbow bit and the camera showing the sign outside the house at the end.

I don't actually know if the thing this segment was from was any good or not, it's just bugging me that I can't recall what it is!  Google results frequently find things for the 2004 Van Helsing film or Abraham Lincoln: Vampire Hunter, but I'm pretty confident it's neither of those.  Definitely not the first, and I haven't seen the second.